# Web and Mobile Analytics: Identifying Users Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, einstein-recommendations

We are trying to get users to be identified on our site. Currently all are coming through as anonymous. We were told to update our script adding the setUserInfo parameters:

_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]); 
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {“email”: “emailaddr”}]); 
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);

Any experience with this. Should this script work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some dynamic code in order to grab the actual email of the user - what you are labeling "emailaddr". As that is just a string, it would just pass that as the actual value of the email (meaning their email would be "emailaddr"). Unless you were just posting that as an example.

If you have a way to gather the information on your website, you can pass that to your collect code script and push it up. The event or data you push to Web Analytics is then identified with that user by through email. You can also pass more details about the user by also pushing a 'details' object.

For me, I was using email conversion tracking from Email Studio which appends query parameters (including the users email address) to the URL and then shoots them onto a landing page, which then converts that into a cookie. My collect code (similar to what you have) has some code to grab the value of the users email from the cookie setting and pass it off to Web Analytics.

See this page for code examples: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/#Setting_Up_Your_Landing_Page